# How can a method which accepts parameters be called without passing it's needed values?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I found this code snippet below on GitHub:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

enum Status { Uninitialized, Authenticated, Authenticating, Unauthenticated }

class UserRepository with ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseAuth auth;
  FirebaseUser _user;
  Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;

  UserRepository.instance({this.auth}) {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(onAuthStateChanged);
  }

  Status get status => _status;
  FirebaseUser get user => _user;

  Future<bool> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future signOut() async {
    auth.signOut();
    _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
    return Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  }

  Future<void> onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) async {
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    } else {
      _user = firebaseUser;
      _status = Status.Authenticated;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

At the top where UserRepository was instantiated,

```
UserRepository.instance({this.auth}) {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(onAuthStateChanged);
  }
```

on `auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen` he passes the `onAuthStatechanged` method. This method as you can see below the code snippet takes in parameter `FirebaseUser firebaseUser` but this is never passed when called.
My question is, how can this work then if it receives no value when called?

Full disclosure: This code isn't mine, it was/is available on GitHub. I only posted it here for whoever has an answer to my question to fully understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen" itself is a function which takes

**Future<void> Function(FirebaseUser)**  as an argument. Function eating function thats all.

OG author could've passed a unnamed function right there like this

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((FirebaseUser firebaseUser){});
```

but that would be less readable

Comment: Oh wow, makes sense now. Thank you very much @Abhi Tripathi.

Comment: I did, but reputation is still below 15. Sorry

Comment: @henrymaykhid Reputation doesn't play any role when it comes to accepting the answer. Press the check mark beneath this post.

Comment: Oh I actually didn't know. Wow, an eye-opener :). I've accepted it. Thanks again